# in Python mock a AsyncGenerator while patching a class method

Tags: python, python-asyncio, pytest-mock

I'm trying to mock a method from a class that returns an asyncGenerator. When mocking a generator everything works fine and I can loop the mocked generator items. But, once I add the class method patch it no longer iterates the generator.
I placed `assert False` to make it easy to notice when it iterates or not.

```
from unittest import mock
from unittest.mock import AsyncMock
import pytest
​
​
class A:
    async def foo(self):
        return 1

​@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_fails_as_expected():
    mock_iterator = AsyncMock()
    mock_iterator.__aiter__.return_value = range(5)
    async for it in mock_iterator:  # type:ignore
        assert it in range(5)
        assert False
​
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_succeeds_unexpectedly():
    mock_iterator = AsyncMock()
    mock_iterator.__aiter__.return_value = range(5)
    a = A()
    with mock.patch.object(A, "foo", new=mock_iterator):
        response = await a.foo()    
        async for _ in response:  # type:ignore
            assert False
```